# LazyITKModule' object has no attribute 'AnalyzeImageIO'

Tags: image, python-2.7, itk, medical

```
from medpy.io import load
import SimpleITK
import vtk

image_data, image_header = load('/Users/N01-T2.mha')
print image_data.shape
```

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/wuzhenglin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/wuzhenglin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/Users/wuzhenglin/Python_nice/SAL_LUNG/test.py", line 140, in <module>
    changeage()
  File "/Users/wuzhenglin/Python_nice/SAL_LUNG/test.py", line 42, in changeage
    image_data, image_header = load('/Users/wuzhenglin/Python_nice/SAL_BRAIN/brain_healthy_dataset/Normal001-T2.mha')
  File "/Users/wuzhenglin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/medpy/io/load.py", line 201, in load
    raise err
medpy.core.exceptions.ImageLoadingError: Failes to load image /Users/wuzhenglin/Python_nice/SAL_BRAIN/brain_healthy_dataset/Normal001-T2.mha as 
Itk/Vtk MetaImage (.mhd, .mha/.raw). Reason signaled by third-party module: 
'LazyITKModule' object has no attribute 'AnalyzeImageIO'
```

I want to deal with .mha image, but it doesn't work.
I have installed medpy, itk and vtk.

I have searched on Google, but there is not related answer to this problem.

Comment: .mha should invoke MetaImageIO, not AnalyzeImageIO. Perhaps report this as an issue on medpy's issue tracker: https://github.com/loli/medpy/issues

Comment: @Dženan Thank you, I have reported the issue and do you have other ways to deal with image.mha with Python?

Answer (score 0):

Does the same error occur without the `import SimpleITK` line? I don't think that is relevant to producing this error.

ITK for Python and `SimpleITK` are two separate Python packages which provide different interfaces to ITK. The error you are seeing is lated to ITK for Python, or the `itk` package on PyPi. Where did you `itk` install come from. Can you run a simple program like this, with your install?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itk
pixelType = itk.UC
imageType = itk.Image[pixelType, 2]
readerType = itk.ImageFileReader[imageType]
```

Comment: After removing `import SimpleITK`, I still can't run those lines of code. And I can run your program and the readerType is `<class 'itkImageFileReaderPython.itkImageFileReaderIUC2'>`

Comment: I use `pip install itk` and `pip install SimpleITK` and `pip install medPy`. Do you think that install process results in this problem ?